# str object has no attribute tk

Tags: python, loops, tkinter

I got 9 tabs in my program and in those tabs I have 5 widgets that are completely the same for every one. So instead of writing a block of identical hand written code I've wanted to use a loop so the program will self-assemble itself. But instead of progress I've got an attribute error. My question is: How can I "persuade" my code that my "x" is not really a "x" but a "f1"("f2", "f3" etc) and its tk attribute was already declared?

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk as ttk
import sqlite3 #importowanie bazy danych
import time
import datetime

litera="f"
class Aplikacja(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    self.grid()

    k=tk.Toplevel(self)
    zakladki=ttk.Notebook(k)
    f1=ttk.Frame(zakladki)
    f2=ttk.Frame(zakladki)
    f3=ttk.Frame(zakladki)
    f4=ttk.Frame(zakladki)
    f5=ttk.Frame(zakladki)
    f6=ttk.Frame(zakladki)
    f7=ttk.Frame(zakladki)
    f8=ttk.Frame(zakladki)
    f9=ttk.Frame(zakladki)
    zakladki.add(f1, text='Czapki')
    zakladki.add(f2, text='Dodatki')
    zakladki.add(f3, text='buty')
    zakladki.add(f4, text='spodnie')
    zakladki.add(f5, text='kurtka')
    zakladki.add(f6, text='T-shirt')
    zakladki.add(f7, text='sweter')
    zakladki.add(f8, text='skarpetki')
    zakladki.add(f9, text='koszula')
    zakladki.grid()
    numznak=1
    while numznak<10:
        znak2=str(numznak)
        #print "numznak: %d" % numznak
        #print "znak2: %s" % znak2
        x=litera+znak2
        #print "x: %s" % x

        tk.Label(x, text='Nazwa').grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.nazwa=tk.Entry(x)
        self.nazwa.grid(row=0, column=1)
        tk.Label(x, text=("Kolor")).grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.kolor=tk.Entry(x)
        self.kolor.grid(row=1, column=1)
        tk.Label(x, text=("Firma:")).grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.firma=tk.Entry(x)
        self.firma.grid(row=2, column=1)

        numznak= numznak +1

root= tk.Tk()
root.title("Szaffa")
root.geometry("180x200")
app= Aplikacja(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You define `x` as a string, but you want to put a `Label` inside?

Comment: i want the program to those build buttons in every tab so i dont have to write <code>tk.Label(f1, text='Nazwa').grid(row=0, column=0) tk.Label(f2, text='Nazwa').grid(row=0, column=0)</code> nine times

Comment: Please post the full error message.  Don't make us guess where the error is.

Comment: Why do you think the variable `x` can be the parent of a widget?

Comment: @TRV: That is why I mention it.  BryanOakley put it better than I.

Comment: @BryanOakley I was hoping there is a way to automate the generation of buttons in the program and using a variable an a loop was my 1 idea

Comment: There is a way to use a loop, of course. Are you aware of what a widget requires for its first argument? What did you expect would happen when you pass in a string to that parameter?

Comment: A better title would be something like "How to make multiple tab frames with the same content?"  This is the question I answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an outer loop for the tab-frame pairs and an inner loop for the label-entry pairs.  I believe the following is a start on what you are looking for.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk

class Aplikacja(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.grid()

        zakladki=ttk.Notebook(parent)
        entries = {}
        for title in ('Czapki', 'Dodatki', 'buty', 'spodnie', 'kurtka',
                      'T-shirt', 'sweter', 'skarpetki', 'koszula'):
            frame = ttk.Frame(zakladki)
            for row, txt in (0, 'Nazwa'), (1, "Kolor"), (2, "Firma"):
                tk.Label(frame, text=txt).grid(row=row, column=0)
                entry = tk.Entry(frame)
                entries[title, txt] = entry
                entry.grid(row=row, column=1)
            zakladki.add(frame, text=title)
        zakladki.grid()

root= tk.Tk()
root.title("Szaffa")
app= Aplikacja(root)
root.mainloop()
```